# plural or singular when using noun as adj

Tags: grammar, adjectives, nouns

> emission**s** data / service**s** industry

I was told when using nouns as adjectives in compound nouns, the nouns should be in their singular form. But I've found many exceptions as listed above. Can you help me to understand the rationale behind?

Comment: These are not compound nouns. "Service industry", for example, is a syntactic construction consisting of "industry" as head and the **noun** "service" as modifier. You'll hear both forms of your examples.

Comment: It's just that ***by default***, in "noun adjunct" usages such as *This garage sells **car tyres***, the "noun used adjectivally" is usually ***singular***. But there are many exceptions, as you've obviously discovered. And it's not obvious to me that assigning different grammatical terminology to those exceptions would help you predict whether you should pluralise or not in some new unfamiliar context.

Comment: ...have a look at [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/397244/2637) to a related ELU question.

Comment: The nouns are not used adjectivally, they are nouns functioning as modifiers. Not everything that modifies a noun is an adjective!